# How to call Kafka Listener from React Js

Tags: javascript, api, apache-kafka

my backend was Springboot and frontend was React Js. I want to send api call to kafka server from react js. i haven't any idea.

```
async apiKafkaListener(path: string, topicId: string){
    const ip = await publicIpv4()
    const headers: any = {
        responseType: 'blob',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        'x-real-ip': `${ip}`,
    }

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(topicId),
    }
    fetch(`${process.env.baseUrl}${path}`, requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {

        }
}
```

Comment: Apache Kafka to WebSocket provides a web-socket server that feeds data from an Apache Kafka topic (s). This is a fantastic tool for analyzing Kafka topics as well using the built-in browser-based consumer., check this link https://github.com/Effyis/kafka2websocket

Answer (score 0):

You don't "call a listener". A Spring-Kafka `KafkaListener` is a consumer, and is asynchonrous, so does not fit into HTTP request-response model.

Also, you can't send requests to Kafka from HTTP. You can send requests to a Spring RESTController, which then forwards data to a KafkaTemplate producer. However, that Spring server could do anything, so your question isn't really a problem dealing with Kafka.

The alternative approach for getting data from a backend Kafka consumer is to connect to a WebSocket hosted by the Spring webserver, and then [connect to that from JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#examples)